# SWT How to print contents of a scrolledComposite?

Tags: java, eclipse, cross-platform, swt

Does anyone know how I would print the contents of a scrolled composite?

Whenver I print onto a GC it will only copy the currently viewable area of the scrolled composite.  What I want is to be able to copy the entire contents of the scrolled composite.

For instance, the code below makes a huge button, inside of a little window.  Whenver I print the gc below, it only will output the small viewable area of the scrolled composite.  Is it possible to print everything in the scrolled composite?

```
Shell shell = new Shell(getDisplay());
shell.setLayout(new FillLayout());
shell.setSize(200, 200);
shell.setLocation(20, 20);


ScrolledComposite sc = new ScrolledComposite(shell, SWT.H_SCROLL| SWT.V_SCROLL);
sc.setMinSize(availWidth, availHeight + 30);

Button b = new Button(sc, SWT.PUSH);
b.setText("Button");
b.setSize(availWidth, availHeight);
sc.setContent(b);

Image image = new Image(getDisplay(), availWidth, availHeight);
GC imageGC = new GC(image);
sc.print(imageGC);
```

Answer (score 2):

**`Note >>>`**

See [@CryptDemon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1332225/cryptdemon) comments below. Though the solution is known to work on Windows 7 and with eclipse 3.7.x release.

---

Yes it is possible. The problem you are facing is due the way Windows paint events are generated (I am assuming Windows OS because I only have that !!) for a **scrolling window**.

At any given moment (as per your code) the visible size of your `scrolled composite` is **less** than the actual size. Now when you call `print()` on your `scrolled composite` then only a part of that (which is at that moment is available/visible) gets printed. Like this:

[image: Border is for clarity]

The **solution** is to create a fixed `Composite` inside your `scrolled composite` and call print on that.

**`Code:`**

```
import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
import org.eclipse.swt.custom.ScrolledComposite;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.SelectionAdapter;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.SelectionEvent;
import org.eclipse.swt.graphics.GC;
import org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Image;
import org.eclipse.swt.graphics.ImageData;
import org.eclipse.swt.graphics.ImageLoader;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.FillLayout;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.GridLayout;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Button;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell;

public class Scrolled 
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        final Display display = new Display();

        Shell shell = new Shell(display);
        shell.setLayout(new FillLayout());
        shell.setSize(200, 200);
        shell.setLocation(20, 20);

        final ScrolledComposite sc = new ScrolledComposite(shell, SWT.BORDER  | SWT.V_SCROLL | SWT.H_SCROLL);
        sc.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,true));

        final Composite innerComposite = new Composite(sc, SWT.NONE);
        innerComposite.setSize(400, 400);
        innerComposite.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, true));

        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
                Button b = new Button(innerComposite, SWT.PUSH);
                b.setText("Text");
                b.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
                    public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) 
                    {
                        Image image = new Image(display, innerComposite.getBounds().width, innerComposite.getBounds().height);
                        ImageLoader loader = new ImageLoader();

                        GC gc = new GC(image);
                        sc.print(gc);
                        gc.dispose();

                        loader.data = new ImageData[]{image.getImageData()};
                        loader.save("c:/temp/out.png", SWT.IMAGE_PNG);
                    }
                });
        }

        sc.setMinSize(innerComposite.computeSize(SWT.DEFAULT, SWT.DEFAULT));
        sc.setContent(innerComposite);
        sc.setExpandHorizontal(true);
        sc.setExpandVertical(true);


        shell.open();
        while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
                if (!display.readAndDispatch())
                        display.sleep();
        }
        display.dispose();
    }
}
```

**`Output:`**

[image]

Comment: Well that appears to work on windows just fine, but it doesn't work on linux systems. The GTK widgets still just print out the viewable area. That's a shame. My program is cross-platform so I really need a solution to this that works on both.

Comment: Oops ! Anyway added `cross-platform` tag to your question.

Answer (score 1):

SWT(GTK3 seems fix this bug), however in our project we intend to keep using SWT(GTK2), our solution is to create a temp shell and reparent contronl to temp shell

```
import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
import org.eclipse.swt.custom.ScrolledComposite;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.SelectionAdapter;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.SelectionEvent;
import org.eclipse.swt.graphics.GC;
import org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Image;
import org.eclipse.swt.graphics.ImageData;
import org.eclipse.swt.graphics.ImageLoader;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.FillLayout;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.GridLayout;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Button;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell;

public class Scrolled {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final Display display = new Display();

        Shell shell = new Shell(display);
        shell.setLayout(new FillLayout());
        shell.setSize(200, 200);
        shell.setLocation(20, 20);

        final ScrolledComposite sc = new ScrolledComposite(shell, SWT.BORDER | SWT.V_SCROLL | SWT.H_SCROLL);
        sc.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, true));

        final Composite innerComposite = new Composite(sc, SWT.NONE);
        innerComposite.setSize(400, 400);
        innerComposite.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, true));

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            Button b = new Button(innerComposite, SWT.PUSH);
            b.setText("Text");
            b.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
                public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
                    Image image = new Image(display, innerComposite.getBounds().width,
                            innerComposite.getBounds().height);
                    ImageLoader loader = new ImageLoader();

                    GC gc = new GC(image);

                    // Create a temp shell and reparent it+
                    Shell newShell = new Shell(shell);
                    newShell.setLayout(new FillLayout());
                    Composite oldParent = sc.getParent();
                    oldParent.setRedraw(false);
                    sc.setParent(newShell);
                    newShell.open();
                    sc.print(gc);
                    sc.setParent(oldParent);
                    oldParent.setRedraw(true);

                    gc.dispose();
                    newShell.dispose();

                    loader.data = new ImageData[] { image.getImageData() };
                    loader.save("./out.png", SWT.IMAGE_PNG);
                }
            });
        }

        sc.setMinSize(innerComposite.computeSize(SWT.DEFAULT, SWT.DEFAULT));
        sc.setContent(innerComposite);
        sc.setExpandHorizontal(true);
        sc.setExpandVertical(true);

        shell.open();
        while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
            if (!display.readAndDispatch())
                display.sleep();
        }
        display.dispose();
    }
}
```