# Grabbing the inherited background image of a SWT component (Scrolled Composite)

Tags: java, eclipse, swt

I have a shell which has a background image. 
Within this shell, I have a scrolled composite. This scrolled composite inherits the background image of the shell.

I would like to perform some sort of alpha blending / gradient on the inherited background image of the scrolled composite.

I follow the codes from [here](http://skounis.blogspot.sg/2008/06/gradient-background-to-any-swt-control.html).

1. `Rectangle rect = sc.getClientArea();` // this rect always returns width and height as 0.
2. `Image newImage = new Image(sc.getDisplay(), Math.max(1, rect.width), rect.height);` // doesn't seems to grab the background image, even if I hardcoded the width and height.

Some codes here:

```
sc = new ScrolledComposite(parent, SWT.BORDER_SOLID | SWT.V_SCROLL);
sc.setExpandHorizontal(true);
sc.setExpandVertical(true);

sc.setAlwaysShowScrollBars(true);
sc.setMinWidth(0);

GridData gd = new GridData(GridData.FILL, GridData.FILL, true, true);
sc.setLayoutData(gd);
sc.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, false));

Rectangle rect = sc.getClientArea();
Image newImage = new Image(sc.getDisplay(), sc.getParent().getBackgroundImage(), SWT.IMAGE_COPY);
GC gc = new GC(newImage);

// need to do clipping on the image so that only the background underlying the scrolled composite gets the gradient

// fill background 
gc.setForeground(new Color(sc.getDisplay(), 100,200,123)); 
gc.setBackground(new Color(sc.getDisplay(), 23,23,23)); 
gc.fillGradientRectangle(rect.x, rect.y, rect.width, rect.height, true);  
gc.dispose();

sc.setBackgroundImage(newImage);
sc.setBackgroundMode(SWT.INHERIT_DEFAULT);


innerComposite = new Composite(sc, SWT.NONE);

GridLayout gl = new GridLayout();
gl.numColumns = 1;
innerComposite.setLayout(gl);
gd = new GridData(GridData.FILL_BOTH);
gd.grabExcessVerticalSpace = true;
innerComposite.setLayoutData(gd);

/**
* Creates other widgets here!
*/
sc.setContent(innerComposite);
sc.layout();
```

Comment: Post some executable code. It would help others to analyze the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One logical problem that I can see here is that you are doing all the gradient stuff too early. Even if you do something like this `sc = new ScrolledComposite(parent, SWT.BORDER_SOLID | SWT.V_SCROLL);` it does not mean the shell is created and ready or the window/composite itself. A very convenient handle is to hook into `SWT.Resize` event.

Anyway check the below code:

#### Output

[image]

#### Code !!

**Note** You have to provide `image.png`

```
import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
import org.eclipse.swt.custom.ScrolledComposite;
import org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Color;
import org.eclipse.swt.graphics.GC;
import org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Image;
import org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Rectangle;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.FillLayout;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.FormLayout;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.GridData;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.GridLayout;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Event;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Label;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Listener;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell;

public class ImageGradientTest {

    private Image imageGradient;
    private Image image;

    private void createComponents(Shell parent) 
    {
        ScrolledComposite sc = new ScrolledComposite(parent, SWT.BORDER_SOLID | SWT.V_SCROLL);
        sc.setExpandHorizontal(true);
        sc.setExpandVertical(true);

        sc.setAlwaysShowScrollBars(true);
        sc.setMinWidth(0);

        GridData gd = new GridData(GridData.FILL, GridData.FILL, true, true);
        sc.setLayoutData(gd);
        sc.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, false));


        final Composite composite = new Composite(sc, SWT.NONE);
        composite.addListener(SWT.Resize, new Listener() {
            public void handleEvent(Event e) {
                changeImage(composite);
            }
        });
        composite.setLayout(new FormLayout());
        composite.setBackgroundMode(SWT.INHERIT_DEFAULT);

        Label label = new Label(composite, SWT.None);
        label.setText("Hello, World!");

        sc.setContent(composite);
        sc.layout();

    }

    private void changeImage(Composite composite) 
    {
        Image oldImage = imageGradient;

        Display display = composite.getDisplay();
        Rectangle rect = composite.getClientArea();
        imageGradient = new Image(display, image, SWT.IMAGE_COPY);


        GC gc = new GC(imageGradient);
        Color color1 = new Color(display, 200, 200, 255);
        Color color2 = new Color(display, 255, 255, 255);

        gc.setAlpha(245);           // Two have a layer effect you should set the alpha
        gc.setForeground(color1);
        gc.setBackground(color2);
        gc.fillGradientRectangle(rect.x, rect.y, rect.width, rect.height, true);

        color2.dispose();
        color1.dispose();
        gc.dispose();


        composite.setBackgroundImage(imageGradient);

        if (oldImage != null) {
            oldImage.dispose();
        }
    }

    private void openShell() 
    {
        Display display = new Display();

        Shell shell = new Shell(display);
        shell.setLayout(new FillLayout());

        image = new Image(display, "image.png");

        shell.setBackgroundImage(image);
        shell.setBackgroundMode(SWT.INHERIT_DEFAULT);

        createComponents(shell);

        shell.open();

        while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
            if (!display.readAndDispatch()) {
                display.sleep();
            }
        }

        image.dispose();
        imageGradient.dispose();        
        display.dispose();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ImageGradientTest sweet = new ImageGradientTest();
        sweet.openShell();
    }
}
```

#### Code for capturing client area image !!

```
Display display = composite.getDisplay();
Rectangle rect = composite.getClientArea();
Image i = new Image(display, composite.getClientArea().width, composite.getClientArea().height);
GC gc = new GC(i);

composite.print(gc);            // This is important

ImageLoader loader = new ImageLoader();
loader.data = new ImageData[]{i.getImageData()};
loader.save("hello.png", SWT.IMAGE_PNG);

gc.dispose();
i.dispose();
```

**Although** [check this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10886789/swt-how-to-print-contents-of-a-scrolledcomposite/10895134#10895134) as the approach is not cross-platform.

Comment: ok lets say the scrolledcomposite is not filled all the way. it occupies only a certain area of the shell. (maybe say 50% centralized) how do you grab this area of the image to perform the gradient/alpha..?

Comment: @humansg - Shouldn't this be a new question. Also, do share some image or snippet. it helps.

Comment: ok. maybe I did not specify clearly on my question. But I want to grab the inherited background portion only. When you set the backgroundmode to inherit_default, and when the sc is not filled up entirely... similar to [here](http://skounis.blogspot.sg/2008/06/gradient-background-to-any-swt-control.html)

Comment: @humansg - if you are just interested in capturing the client area image of scrollcomposite then check my updated answer

Comment: hey thanks for ur help.. i got the idea now. as u mentioned in ur answer, i am doing all the things too early..before even the shell got layout. I guess i need to call those functions after the shell has been laid out so I can get the width/height of the composite and it's position etc... just wondering if `SWT.Resize` will be fired when the shell is being layout the first time or ONLY a manual resize of the shell will cause it to be fired??

Comment: @humansg - for both. try it out. put a sysout statement in the resize handler and see.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Control.getBackgroundImage()` to get the background image. Just traverse through the widget hierarchy until you find and image using some logic like 
`while (myControl.getParent().getBackgroundImage == null)`

Comment: this is a great idea. but how do i "cut out" the image portion that the sc is laid on? Will need to get the relative position I guess..? But sc.getClientArea() is not showing things..